# Execute at command from php page with command line input

Tags: php, task, scheduling, at-job

I want to execute the below command from PHP shell_script in Linux environment.

```
shell_exec('at 12:39 <<< "mkdir newfolder"');
```

I have tried in all the method of PHP to execute this script but it is not working.
 In terminal when I am running `at 12:39 <<< "mkdir newfolder"` it is executing and the task is scheduling.But when I am trying the same script to run in php by using shell_exec it is not working.

You can understand the issues when you type `at 12:39` it will show you to put the input and press Ctrl+d to complete execution. to make this in a single line here I am using `<<<`

Can anyone suggest how can I execute this script from the PHP?

Answer (score 2):

shell_exec uses dash shell system by default : to make sure run `php -r 'echo shell_exec("echo $0");'` and it will output 'sh' , and Dash does not have the <<< redirection operator.

Instead you could force the use of Bash  and do something like:

```
shell_exec('/bin/bash -c \'at 12:39 <<< "mkdir newfolder"\'');
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks Yacine for you answer, the script you have mention is returning false and also the task is also not scheduling. can you please try this and suggest me an answer.

Comment: if I am running this `php -r 'echo shell_exec("echo $0");'`   in terminal then it is working fine but when I am running using shell_exec `shell_exec('/bin/bash -c \'at 12:39 <<< "mkdir newfolder"\'');`  it is not working

Comment: Are you running the script using php command or from the webserver ?

Comment: If it is from the webserver it could be a permission issue as www-data user doesn't have the permission to run the 'at' command (see the file /etc/at.deny if it contains www-data entry ).

Comment: yes, there is a file called at.deny, but it is not opening with the text editor. Can you suggest me how to open and how to edit this file so that I can execute this command in the server.

Comment: Try sudo nano /etc/at.deny . This will work if the current user is sudoer.

Comment: Thank you. The www-data is present in the file, Should I remove or anything I have do to that file.

Comment: Removing www-data entry would fix the issue, but to be honest I don't understand why www-data is listed in at.deny file!

Comment: Thanks, the permission was the real issue. Worked like a charm once I gave myself permission.. :)